# Does Google MAP API Use Async Request

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I wrote a small app to test out Google Map API and I noticed that my functions do not execcute in the expected order. Please take a look at my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><htm><head><title></title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">  </script>
<script>
//Global Variables
var lat, lng, _Address;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

// Make the Geocode request    
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (searchResults,searchStatus)   {
    if (searchStatus !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert("Your search yields " + searchStatus);
    }
    // Checking to see if the Geocode Status is OK before proceeding
    if (searchStatus == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(searchResults);
        _Address = (searchResults[0].formatted_address);            
        alert("First time Address is displayed" + _Address);
    }
   }); 
}

function splitAddress() {    
var addressArr = _Address.split(',');     
//addressArr will be used later   
}

// This function is called when the submit button is clicked
function SearchAddress() {        
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139" }, function (searchResults, searchStatus) {
        var location = searchResults[0].geometry.location;
        lat = location.lat();
        lng = location.lng();            
        getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng);
        alert("Second time Address is displayed" + _Address);
        splitAddress();
    });}
</script></head><body><div><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SearchAddress()"></div></body></html>
```

When I set a break point on the line alert("First time Address is displayed" + _Address), I can tell that this alert function executes before the line alert("Second time Address is displayed" + _Address).

However, the line alert("Second time Address is displayed" + _Address) appears as though it executes first and the value of _Address is undefined. So my question is if the second alert function executes after the first alert function, is Google Map API making an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Maps API uses asynchronous requests when you call  `geocoder.geocode`.

This is in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps
>   API needs to make a call to an external server.